Ubuntu 24.10: desktop icons are sorted by name instead of my own layout after reboot / wake up
I've been sitting on Ubuntu for about six years, and all that time desktop icons were spread on the screen as I wished, here & there, and stayed on their places. Now, after upgrade to 24.10, they get sorted by name and bound to the desktop's upper side every time I boot or wake up my PC.
I digged some forums, but couldn't find a solution. Icons/Sort is set to Unsorted, Icons/Locked doesn't help at all. Permissions to /home/$USER/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/ are ok (775). What else could be done?
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.10
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.6.0
Qt Version: 6.6.2
Kernel Version: 6.11.0-8-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland

WMBR, George Hazan.
